maximum between martingale and constant
I want to understand if $(M_t\vee K)_{t\geq0}$ is a martingale?. Where $M$ is a martingale and $K$ is a positive constant. It is easy to see that it is a submartingale, but I am wondering if it is possible for it to be a martingale. My naive reasoning is as follows: if $M_t\geq K$ then  $\mathbb{E}[M_t\vee K|\mathcal{F}_s]=\mathbb{E}[M_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=M_s$ and $M_t\leq K$ implies $\mathbb{E}[M_t\vee K|\mathcal{F}_s]=K$, but it happens  only when the inequalities holds w.p.1. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Consider standard Brownian motion $(B_t)$. This is a martingale. If $B_t\vee 1$ is a martingale, then $E(B_t \vee 1)=E(B_0\vee 1)=1$. But then $ E[(B_t \vee 1)-1]=0$ which implies $B_t \le 1$ a.s.. This is a contradiction since $B_t$ has normal distribution.

Thank you for the couter example. It is easy to understand.
